# How to send user to the billing information page immediately after logging in?

Tags: 7, commerce

I am creating a subscription site using Drupal commerce. My site uses logintoboggan  to login a user after creating an account. I am planning to create an order programmatically and then redirect the user to the page where they can enter their credit card information and billing information. I have not figured out how to redirect them to that page yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Login Destination](https://drupal.org/project/login_destination) module - it allows you to define destination rules for logging in/registering users and even use PHP snippets for custom conditions.